# ClearInterval Not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, intervals

i'm try to clear interval when the user in not in the detail section and if match the status is 1, my code like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(section)
    console.log('ini interval lo', interval)
    if (section !== "detailCheckIn") {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('aa', clearInterval(interval) ? true : false)
    }

    console.log('section di : ', section)
  }, [section]);

  const checkStatus = (data) => {
    console.log('datanya nih ', data)

    interval = setInterval(() => {

      console.log('ini test interval', userToken)
      consume.getWithParams('CheckinInfo', {}, { token     }, { checkin_id: data })
        .then(response => {

          console.log('ini tuh response', response)
          //ubah jadi 1 kalomau final test
          if (response.result.status === 1) {
            navigation.navigate('Service')
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log('di clear')
            AsyncStorage.setItem('isCheckIn', 'udah check in nih')
          }

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          console.log('token error', token)
        })

    }, 2000);
  }
```

[image]

when i'm console log the clear interval, that return false

Comment: `clearInterval` is a function that does not return anything. All it does is clear a timer you define in `setInterval` and nothing else. The second red box here is clearing the interval you define within the `checkStatus` function, and I believe it should work. I don't see where the interval in your `useEffect` is declared. Whatever it is, it is not the same interval you declare inside `checkStatus`. You want to look at `useRef`, for storing a single mutable value (in this case your interval) that is accessible from anywhere in the component: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question, pasting all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour] and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Comment: in this case i want to check in the database if the status is 1, do you have any suggestions to i use to doing that beside using interval to chech the data ?

Comment: If you want to keep checking then an interval is probably the easiest way. You might want to limit the number of calls you make, like no more than 20 attempts or something, or reducing the frequency of calls to one every 5 seconds instead of every second. But that depends on how much you're bothered by having your server deal with lots of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Notice the use of `useRef` to store a single reference to `_interval`, and how this is only ever changed through the functions `clearCurrentInterval` and `replaceCurrentInterval`.

If you only update your interval through these two functions, you can be sure you will only ever have one interval at a time, as your previous interval always gets cleared first.

```js
  const _interval = useRef(null);
  const interval = () => _interval.current;

  const clearCurrentInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(interval());
  };

  const replaceCurrentInterval = (newInterval) => {
    clearCurrentInterval();
    _interval.current = newInterval;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(section);
    console.log("ini interval lo", interval());
    if (section !== "detailCheckIn") {
      clearCurrentInterval();
    }

    console.log("section di : ", section);
  }, [section]);

  const checkStatus = (data) => {
    console.log("datanya nih ", data);

    const newInterval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("ini test interval", userToken);
      consume
        .getWithParams("CheckinInfo", {}, { token }, { checkin_id: data })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("ini tuh response", response);
          //ubah jadi 1 kalomau final test
          if (response.result.status === 1) {
            navigation.navigate("Service");
            clearCurrentInterval();
            console.log("di clear");
            AsyncStorage.setItem("isCheckIn", "udah check in nih");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          console.log("token error", token);
        });
    }, 2000);

    replaceCurrentInterval(newInterval);
  };
```

However, depending on how you're using this, you might be better off just having a  `useEffect` that creates a single interval when the component mounts, and clears it when it unmounts or gets the API response you want.